# New Members Of Stack Exchange Family

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange, new-users

Where, what, how, when, is the correct place, time, and environment to discuss other Stack Exchange sites? I'm thinking that there are probably one zillion ideas floating around in the minds of the users; now how could any of these become concrete and useful as Stack Overflow ?

Or, is this the place ?

I haven't been here even a month, and I'm guessing that 90% (and then some) of my time has been in Stack Overflow trying to learn from the experts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is such a place, it's called http://Area51.stackexchange.com

Comment: I like the outer-space artwork. WO !!!! VHDL !!!  Can I quit my job and work for you guys ? Hmmm, ratZ, I'm totally low-level; nothing on the web or any such thing. Hey, thanks a lot; a whole lot. I wish I had found this place 10 years ago.

Comment: Okay, so I found one to follow; probably dozens on there. I click on "follow", however, he doesn't know who I am, and asks for my E-mail address. Should I use the same one I use for my StackExchange log in ?

Comment: @User.1: You can use the same login, yes. It works the same as the other StackExchange sites, just as on Stack Overflow and here.